# Akka custom logger

Tags: logging, akka, slf4j

There is akka application that uses akka logging and slf4j over logback:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

What I need is to format messages whenever I use log in some actor, e.g.:

```
log.debug("my object is {}", MyAwesomeFormatter.format(anyObject))
```

To avoid using `MyAwesomeFormatter` in every log call I want to create some adapter that will do it under the hood and respect log level laziness:

```
def debug(t: String, arg: Any*): Unit = { if (isDebugEnabled) format(t, arg.map(MyAwesomeFormatter.format(_)): _*) }
```

The only way I found how to achieve this is to extends from `ActorLogging` trait along with overriding `LoggingAdapter`. In such case I would need to mixin new `FormattedActorLogging` (that will provide new adapter) into actor instead of `ActorLogging`. But there are so much actors that should be altered.

Is there any way how to just specify new logger by config?:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["com.my.AwesomeLogger"]  
}
```

Seems like that `AwesomeLogger` should be an actor and will receive already filled with placeholders messages, so there is no way to place formatting logic in that actor.

Thanks in advance for ideas!